# Selenium: is it possible to select dropdown option by html element rather than value/label/index

Tags: html, xpath, selenium

Selenium has a select statement that allows you to pass in two locators.  From the documentation I could find, it looks like the second locator has to basically resolve to a  the label/value/index of the element.  It seems strange to me that if it accepts a locator for that argument, it wouldn't just allow you to pass in a locator identifying the  element itself.  When I try to do that I get an error that there is no option with label [full locator text].  I know this is not essential (e.g. you can easily get the label text from that locator) but it just seems clean and intuitive to me; is this possible?

Comment: What statement is that? What are you exactly trying that is giving the error?

Comment: give us the sample html. And then tell us what you want and what not. Also mention which binding you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you feel any selenium method is not clean or flexible enough....you can always write a wrapper for that method and add your own logic.

Example:- For selenium click() method, you can write a wrapper like below,

```
private void customClick(){
selenium.isElementPresent(locator);
selenium.click(locator);
}
```

The code is for Selenium RC API, you can implement similar idea for WebDriver as well....